# How to setup the path in winston and app.module.ts for Linux and Windows localhost

Tags: linux, windows, nestjs, devops, winston

I cannot be the first developing on Windows 10 and wanting the log-files in dev mode on the localhost and pump/pipe it into `/var/logs/myservice` folder if it is in integration or production.

How can one replace the window path with a linux path according to environment variables?

In this case I use winston and nestjs.

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { EventEmitterModule } from '@nestjs/event-emitter';
import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import { AppGateway } from './app.gateway';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { WinstonModule } from 'nest-winston';
import * as winston from 'winston';


@Module({
  imports: [ 
    WinstonModule.forRoot({
      level: 'info',
      format: winston.format.json(),
      defaultMeta: { service: 'trading-signal-listener' },
      transports: [
        //
        // - Write all logs with level `error` and below to `error.log`
        // - Write all logs with level `info` and below to `combined.log`
        //
        new winston.transports.File({ filename: 'error.log', level: 'error' }),
        new winston.transports.File({ filename: 'combined.log' }),
      ],
    }),
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what's your problem, can't you just use `@nestjs/config` as described here https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/configuration and based on environment variables pass a specific path to your WinstonModule?

One would use the regular `process.env` variable and it works.

```
new winston.transports.File({ filename: process.env.logfile}),
        new winston.transports.File({ filename: process.env.errorfile, level: 'error' }),
```

Comment: Yes, that would be the intention. But this is a app.module.ts decorator, which takes the option values. It's not in the main code. How would you "inject" the path variables in the options?

Comment: @feder take a look at the documentation of nest-winston https://www.npmjs.com/package/nest-winston#user-content-async-configuration here, there is an example how to pass WinstonConfigService that you may create by your own and inject your specific configuration by your very own :)

Comment: I've added it to you answer before :-) Thanks for the hint.